# rospy master status

Tags: ros, rospy, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a tool for checking if the rosmaster is up using rospy?

Something along the lines of
[roscpp's ros::master::check()](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1master.html#a6428e7e3468e4e9ab69b75f75d63510d)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61304/rospy-master-status/) by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 204 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might not be the best answer but the sample code in [Master_API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API) page might work for your purpose. If no `master` is running, the follwoing line would fail with `socket.error`:

```
code, msg, val = m.getSystemState(caller_id)
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1